# How to start mysql service automatically as root user.

Tags: mysql, sql, linux-headers

Since mysql on my system is able to run using `sudo service mysql start` i used the username root it self.. the problem is now I want to automatically run the script

Comment: What version of Ubutu is this?

Comment: What command did you use to check the status?

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you install mysql it is set to run at boot, so I don't know why yours isn't. Now the version of Ubuntu you use is also important:

1. Ubuntu 14.04 and below:

   - enable run at boot:

     ```
     sudo update-rc.d mysql enable
     ```
2. Ubuntu 15.04 and above:

   - enable at boot:

     ```
     sudo systemctl enable mysql
     ```

Comment: Hi, ```Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory```

I got this error if I check the status

Comment: Temporary solution to  automate is to use .bashrc and run it during shell boot-up ```sudo service mysql start```